# Is there a way to check where did the segmentation fault happened using gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

When I run my object test file, I got segmentation fault so I use gdb to find where is the bug. However, when I do gdb (my object file), I stepped through the file using next but there aren't any errors in it. I am kind of confused, is there a good way to find where did segmentation fault happen? Thank you in advance.

This is what I did in gdb:

```
(gdb) n
44        if (argc > 1) {
(gdb) n
45          tctest_testname_to_execute = argv[1];
(gdb) n
48        TEST(testGetWidth);
(gdb) n
49        TEST(testGetHeight);
(gdb) n
50        TEST(testGetTile);
(gdb) n
52        TEST_FINI();
(gdb) n
All tests passed!
```

This is the error I got when I run my object file:

```
segmentation fault
segmentation fault
segmentation fault
3 test(s) failed
```

(edit)
Hi, sorry for the late update, I tried debugging it on my end but I still got no luck yet. I am trying to create a maze class that can read an input stream that has the description of the maze and return a maze. However when I run a test with this given input stream:

```
20 10
####################
#................<.#
#..................#
#...###............#
#.....#............#
#.....#............#
#...###............#
#..................#
#..................#
####################
```

It gives a segmentation fault, and I run the object file on valgrind to check what is happening:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==2482545==    at 0x4032CD: Maze::setTile(Position const&, Tile*) (maze.cpp:47)
==2482545==    by 0x40347B: Maze::read(std::istream&) (maze.cpp:67)
.....
==2482545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I don't really understand why there is an segmentation fault or an invalid write, in my code, I should have allocated the space for each tile inside my setTile function, so there should be space for me to write. I also stacked the tile_collection with my constructor so tile_collection should be initialized when I called Maze(20,10), and the resizing inside setTile should be working. Can you please point out what am I missing? Thank you in advance.
This is my header file that excludes the function declarations:

```
class Maze {
private:
  // TODO: add fields
  int Width;
  int Height;
  std::vector<Tile*> tile_collection;
```

This is my cpp file:

```
Maze::Maze(int width,int height):
  Width(width),Height(height){
  tile_collection[(height)*(width-1)];
}


void Maze::setTile(const Position &pos,Tile *tile){
  tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);
  tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;
}


Maze *Maze::read(std::istream &in){
  int x;int y;char c;
  if ((in>>x)&&(in>>y)){
      Maze *new_maze=new Maze(x,y);
      //loop over the specified maze dimension
        for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<x;j++){
            if (in>>c){
              //using tilefactory to change character into a tile
              TileFactory *fac=fac->getInstance();
              Tile* temp=fac->createFromChar(c);
              //if createFromChar fails, return nullptr, otherwise set tile at position j,i
              if (temp==nullptr){
                return nullptr;
              }
              else{
                new_maze->setTile(Position(j,i),temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return new_maze;
  }
  else{
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: A `segmentation fault` occurs when accessing a restricted area in memory. It might Indicate that you have a memory access that is sometimes a part of your application's memory, sometimes - not. Try to check for warning, use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), or post your code.

Comment: Do you want to reproduce segmentation fault in gdb?

Comment: Do you know what program  is printing `segmentation fault` ? The shell will print `Segmentation fault` with  capital S. If it's your own program, can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: In any case, typing `set disable-randomization off` in gdb before running your program may allow those segmentation faults to happen, but I'm not sure if they occur in your program or in some other process. Can you describe how your program creates and runs other processes?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick hi, I tried that and got where the segmentation faults happened-- it happened when I call the setTile function

Comment: OK, looking at your code... After `tile_collection.resize(pos.getX()+pos.getY()*Width);` you have `tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;`, but that's accessing one element beyond the capacity of the vector. Sometimes the vector has extra capacity, sometimes not. It's recommended that you use the `.at` method instead of square brackets so that you'll get a named exception (`out_of_range`) instead of a segfault if you access something out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)...) can produce a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). See [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html). You may need to enable them (e.g. with some appropriate `ulimit` builtin in your terminal, see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) done by your shell).

The [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) is capable of analyzing post mortem such `core` files.

Of course, compile your C++ code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a great way to trace Seg Faults using gdb](https://youtu.be/PorfLSr3DDI?t=532) with reversible debugging